# GooglePlayServicesUtil isUserRecoverableError Android

Tags: android, service

> ```
>         int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
>                 .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(rootView.getContext());
>         if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
>             if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
>                 GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(),
>                         PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
>             } else {
>                 Toast toast = Toast
>                         .makeText(
>                                 rootView.getContext(),
>                                 R.string.googleServices,
>                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>                 toast.show();
>             }
> ```

Here is the problem, the popup shows up GooglePlayServicesUtil isUserRecoverableError , but when i click on get google play services.it does nothing and doesn't download anything or update.